# How to ignore palm swipe event on Samsung Galaxy 3

Tags: android, events, gesture

I have some buttons in my Android app which play a tone when pressed and stop playing when the button is released. I use code as below to implement this

```
  private OnTouchListener dialTouch = new OnTouchListener() 
  {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
         if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            {   
                 //play tone
            }
            else  if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
            {
                    // stop tone
            }
     }
  }
```

However on a Samsung Galaxy 3 the palm swipe feature eg when taking a screenshot is triggering these MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN events. Is there any way to ignore the palm swipe event in the code but still be able to generate the tone on press of the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I know this is old, but did you even get it answered ? I really need to know how to turn off the palm sweep listener

Answer (score 0):

I also want to know the Answer for this question.
Does android has any palm swipe listener itself , or we need to do this programatically by using our logic.